The shape squashes sharply but I want it to be curved, what can I do to fix this?
I am trying to create a mannequin model where the abdomen box bends and twists when I move the thorax or pelvis. The stretched side (left from viewer) looks good but the squashed side looks weird.

I want it to be curved like the stretched side but its sharp. What can I do to fix this?

i would recommend searching for "blender armature shape keys". There are dozens of tutorials on yt and answer here.

Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
